# Plotting a bar chart in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date         Day_of_month                                                           
2017/1/16    16
2016/2/16    16
2018/1/16    16
2015/1/17    17
2013/1/18    18
```

How do I draw a bar plot on the day of the month on the x-axis and the number of entries of a specific day of the month (e.g. 16) on the y-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) and last [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df['Day_of_month'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
```

[image]